# probability that one of several equally likely choices is made more frequently than expected in multiple trials

Tags: probability

> How can I calculate the probability that one choice among several is made more (or less) frequently that expected?

For example, subjects are given $4$ options and so we expect each option to be chosen $1/4$ of the time.  If there are $20$ subjects making one choice each, we expect each option to be chosen $5$ times.  Suppose some option is chosen $8$ times (out the the twenty trials).  What is the probability of that the actual outcome $(8)$ exceeds the expected outcome $(5)$ by $3$?

Stated more generally, with $k$ options each with probability $1/k$ of being chosen and $n$ trials the expected number of times each option is chosen is $n/k$.  If $c_i$ is the number of times $i$th choice was made, what is the probability that $|c_i - n/k| > 0$?

Comment: If $n$ is not an exact multiple of $k$ then  $\mathbb P(|c_i -n/k|>0)=1$.  Otherwise, are you interested in a particular $i$, or any $i$, or all the $i$s not having exactly the expected value?  For a particular $i$ you can use the binomial distribution.

Comment: I think on that last line you probably want to drop those absolute value bars. Assuming the choices are independent, you can use the binomial distribution.

Comment: I realize the problem with n/k not being an integer but didn't know how to deal with it (round down? (if n>>k?).  I included the absolute value bars because fewer than expected choices is as interesting as more.
I'm not interested in any particular 'i' (choice) - just the one's with large deviations from the expected value (for which I'd like to know the likelihood.  Thank you both